# Groovy Script to add new phase job to multi-job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-groovy

For the already available multi-job in jenkins, need to add new phase jobs using Groovy Scripting. I have written the following groovy code which adds up an already existing job p25_deploy-1. 
This code is working to create the multi-job but the phase job is not showing as mapped in the Jenkins UI. Where as if I see it `config.xml`, its created properly as expected except a tag `<killPhaseOnJobResultCondition>`. Not sure why the phase job is not mapped properly?

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig.KillPhaseOnJobResultCondition.*
import java.lang.String.*
import hudson.model.Descriptor;
import hudson.tasks.Builder;

def jenkinsInstance = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance

def templateJobName = 'profile_p25'

def templateJob = jenkinsInstance.getJob(templateJobName)


 // get MultiJob BuildPhases and clone each PhaseJob
 builders = templateJob.getBuilders();

builders.each { b ->
if (b instanceof MultiJobBuilder){
def pj = b.getPhaseJobs()

   hudson.model.Describable p1 = new PhaseJobsConfig("p25_deploy-1",null,
        true,PhaseJobsConfig.KillPhaseOnJobResultCondition NEVER,null,false,false,null,0,false,true,null,false,false)
   pj.add(p1)
   }  
 }

    templateJob.save()
   // update dependencies
    jenkinsInstance.rebuildDependencyGraph()
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Have tried many ways but was not able to figure out the problem with the script.

We can use DSL to create but I wanted it to be done in Groovy Scripting and moreover modify the existing job.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Yay! I am back with the answer for my question. Have tried this since very long time. Finally am able to make it though. I was aware that solution would be really simple but not able to figure out the hack of it.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig.KillPhaseOnJobResultCondition.*
import java.lang.String.* 
import hudson.model.Descriptor
import hudson.tasks.Builder

def jenkinsInstance = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance

def templateJobName = 'profile_p25'

def templateJob = jenkinsInstance.getJob(templateJobName)

// get MultiJob BuildPhases and clone each PhaseJob
builders = templateJob.getBuilders();

builders.each { b -> if (b instanceof MultiJobBuilder)
    { def pj =
        b.getPhaseJobs()

        hudson.model.Describable newphase = new
        PhaseJobsConfig(deploys[i],null,
            true,null,null,false,false,null,0,false,false,"",false,false)
            newphase.killPhaseOnJobResultCondition = 'NEVER'
            pj.add(newphase)    
    }
}
templateJob.save()
```